# Python: Connect 4 board

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a connect 4 board using sublists but the code below is for a 6x7 board. I want to change it so it can customize to whatever size the user wants it to be. i need some help because i don't know how to change it.

```
ttt_board = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "],
              [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "],
              [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
              [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]
```

Comment: How does user input size?

Comment: i ask the user for how many rows and columns they would like.

Comment: You probably meant to use list comprehension: `ttt_board = [[" "]*8 for i in range(6)]`

Comment: @alfasin Why not `[[" "]*8]*6`? ;)

Comment: @Bugs +1 cause it feels to short... :D

Comment: @Bugs because if you generate the board like that, you end up with all the rows being the same list.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehensions.

`[[" " for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]]` (Where width and height are the values your user inputs, of course.)

**Why does this work?**

First, the `range` function generates integers between two endpoints.  If you omit the first endpoint, it defaults to 0.  So `range(5)` will give `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

A list comprehension generates a list based on two things:  an expression for the elements of the list and an expression on which to base the length of the list.  This takes the form [x for y in z] as seen above.

`x` is the expression for each element - in this case, a constant value.

`y` is a value that gets bound to each element of `z`, although in this case we don't use it.

and `z` is an iterable for binding `y` (which is kind of redundant given the last thing I said).

For a more complicated example that involves using the bindings, consider the following:

`a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]`

`b = [len(x) for x in a])`

Now we have `b` as `[3,3,5,4]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the rows and columns dynamically:

```
board = [[" " for _ in range(col_count)] 
         for _ in range(row_count)]
```